# Php - add session items to an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Instead of adding the from session items to an array like this

```
$itemlist[0] = $_SESSION['item1'];
$itemlist[1] = $_SESSION['item2'];
$itemlist[2] = $_SESSION['item3'];
```

Is there a way to add the items like this?

```
$itemlist = array();

for ($index = 0; $index <= 10; $index++){
    $itemlist[$index] = $_SESSION['item{$index +1}'];
}

echo $itemlist;
```

Comment: Perhaps like `$_SESSION['item'.($index +1)]`

Comment: This is it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have single quotes not double quotes.

try to replace:

```
$itemist[$index] = $_SESSION['item{$index +1}'];
```

with

```
$itemist[$index] = $_SESSION["item{$index +1}"];
```

Comment: That did not fix it!

Comment: well I'm still new at it